# Spring multipart file upload with gridfs size limit exception

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jhipster, gridfs

Using Jhipster with Spring+Mongo and Gridfs to handle files saved in db. When I'm trying to upload files larger than 1Mb it gives me an 500 error:

```
java.io.IOException: UT000054: The maximum size 1048576 for an individual file in a multipart request was exceeded
```

Tried to set this in application-dev.yml without success:

```
spring:
    http:
        multipart:
            max-file-size: 10MB
            max-request-size: 10MB
```

How could this limit be changed?

Comment: Which version of spring-boot are you using?

Comment: @araknoid 1.5.2

Answer (score 7):

Try this,

```
spring:
    servlet:
        multipart:
            max-file-size: 10MB
            max-request-size: 10MB
```

Answer (score 3):

as JHipster uses undertow, a way of fixing this is setting the upload size in a multipart resolver bean like this:

```
@Configuration
public class UndertowConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.http.multipart.max-file-size:10}")
    private long maxFileSize;

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        multipartResolver.setResolveLazily(true);
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(1024*1024*maxFileSize);
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(1024*1024*maxFileSize);
        return multipartResolver;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this content to WebConfigurer if exist

```
@Bean

public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {

     MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();

     factory.setMaxFileSize("100MB");

     factory.setMaxRequestSize("100MB");

     return factory.createMultipartConfig();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of configuring it in your `application-dev.yml`, you can configure these 2 properties in your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

For additional information, you can give a check to [Spring Uploading file](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) guide.

As a side note, if you decide later on to migrate to **spring-boot 2.0**, these properties have changed from `spring.http.multipart` to `spring.servlet.multipart`.

Comment: I don't have `application.properties` but `application.yml`. Tried there, no effect. As I know `application-dev.yml` should override `application.yml` settings. Anyway, I have it in both, still not working.

Comment: Are you sure spring boot is picking correctly your application-dev.yml file? Are there any other yml file?

Comment: yes, using application-dev.yml for some other settings as well without problems

Comment: `spring.http.multipart` is removed and we have to use `spring.servlet.multipart` as in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M6/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration .

Comment: @Xdg You are correct, and thanks for the reminder. The question was made for SpringBoot 1.5.2. For a previous comment, I added a note at the end for the Spring Boot 2.0 changes.

Answer (score 0):

For spring boot2.x:

```
spring:
    servlet:
        multipart:
            max-file-size: 10MB
            max-request-size: 10MB
```

and for older version

```
spring:
    http:
        multipart:
            max-file-size: 10MB
            max-request-size: 10MB
```

For unlimited upload file size, set setting max-file-size: -1 will make it for infinite file size.